# Why is my membership length only "Six months"?

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winterbash-leaderboard

I was viewing the [Stack Exchange Winter Bash Leaderboard](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) and I noticed that I've apparently only had my account for six months, which is news to me... I opened my first site account here in February of 2014.

[image: Six months old only?]

My account is much older than this, what's causing this bug?

---

To add some detail... On the per-site list, it does line up the "member for X" text with my actual membership time on that site. For example, when I look at the Meta Stack Exchange leaderboard, it shows me as a member for 2 years, 10 months. This is expected.

---

#### Update.

With some work, today, I've managed to exceed my Interpersonal Skills hat count of with my Meta Stack Exchange hat count. This has changed my account age to match my MSE account age...

[image: Update! More hats, longer user age.]

Still not reflective of my actual age... but better.

Comment: You wretched noob :-P

Comment: @Randal'Thor you could at least take pity on me. :( Poor infantile user.

Comment: Is there a specific site that you joined 6 months ago?

Comment: Still seeing this problem in 2020 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358211/winter-bash-network-wide-leaderboard-shows-wrong-membership-length

Answer (score 4):

To answer that, we need to investigate how the network leaderboard decides which per-site profile to link to.  When I clicked on your profile there it took me to IPS, where you've been a member for...about six months.  (I guess it doesn't go to the network profile because there are no hats there.)

I looked at my own, which takes me to Mi Yodeya, my oldest account (other than Area 51).  For neither of us is the chosen site our top in reputation.

I looked at a few other examples, and my theory is that it links to the site where you have the most hats.  You can test that theory for us by earning more hats on a different site and seeing if your entry changes.  (Unless the association was fixed at the time you got your first hat.  We'll never know if you don't try.)

Comment: Is Mi Yodeya your chat parent account by any chance?

Comment: Yes, but chat is a separate system.  [Mithrandir](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/33591/mithrandir)'s leaderboard entry links to SF&F but that's not his chat parent.

Comment: Hmmm. That's sort of a silly way to determine account age.

Comment: What it seems to be doing is: check your hat box, pick your most hatty site, link that profile, and use *its* age.  I doubt that last part was intentional.

Comment: I've just surpassed my IPS hat count on MSE and the account age has switched to the MSE age... so this is correct... now I need them to fix it :P

Comment: @Catija thank you for your contribution to science.

Comment: HA HA! I actually am really far ahead of the pack on IPS, so I was focusing here because I wasn't in first place :P One more hat will get me two!

Comment: Well... I decided to prioritize MSE since there's not much competition on IPS :P

Comment: Yeah... but, considering the rapidity of balpha's response to some of the other bug posts, I have a feeling the "bug" part will not be addressed.

Comment: Oh, it was tagged bug -- oops, missed that.