# Winter Bash Network-Wide Leaderboard shows wrong membership length

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, winterbash-leaderboard

On the [network-wide leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) for the Winter Bash, it seems to show your membership time on only one site, though that site might not be the site you've been on longest. (Maybe it's showing the site you have the most hats on?)

For example, my entry on the leaderboard shows me as only being a member on the network for 9 months. This is true for Meta Stack Exchange, however I've been on the network for [more than 7 years](https://stackexchange.com/users/3625223/kylejrp?tab=accounts).

[image: A screenshot of my profile on the Winter Bash leaderboard, showing that I have been a member for 9 months.]

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question I asked a while back (years ago)... It's possible that it's not fixable... or just not urgent enough for us to worry about fixing.